# Generating report results in an unhandled exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' occurred in system.windows.forms.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I'm creating a crystal report in Visual Studio 2012 but I keep getting an error of

```
an unhandled exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' occurred in system.windows.forms.dll
```

Here my code for Form 4:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalReport1 r = new CrystalReport1();
        maintenance_productDataSetTableAdapters.COLOR_TYPETableAdapter ta = new EBL.maintenance_productDataSetTableAdapters.COLOR_TYPETableAdapter();
        maintenance_productDataSet.COLOR_TYPEDataTable table = ta.GetData();
        r.SetDataSource(table.DefaultView);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Form4 the one load when I start to run the VS 2012.

I also tried to use DataSet but it has the same error. Code with DataSet:

```
CrystalReport1 rep = new CrystalReport1();
DataSet1TableAdapters.COLOR_TYPETableAdapter ta = new Weeak.DataSet1TableAdapters.COLOR_TYPETableAdapter();
DataSet1.COLOR_TYPEDataTable table = ta.GetData();
rep.SetDataSource(table.DefaultView);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Crystal Report was developed using an earlier version of the .NET Framework, you need to add these lines to your `app.config` file:

```xml
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening here is the following events are happening

1. `InitializeComponent` calls `CreateControl`
2. `CreateControl` raises the `Load` event
3. `Form4_Load` eventually calls `Refresh` which eventually calls `CreateControl`

At this point steps 2 and 3 mutually recurse each other and end up causing a stack overflow exception.  To fix this simply move the code from the `Form4_Load` method to immediately after the `InitializeComponent` call in the constructor